# Can't resize texture to 100 % within smaller viewport

Tags: c++, directx

In my game I have a small viewport that has a live render of the game the problem I seem to have is that I cannot resize the texture to fix into the viewport, I've achieved the task before with this but it seems to not work like this.

```
->GetLevelDesc(0, &desc);
D3DXVECTOR2 scale = D3DXVECTOR2(desc.Width, desc.Height);
D3DXMatrixTransformation2D(&matrix, NULL, 0, &scale, NULL, 0, NULL);
->SetTransform(D3DTS_TEXTURE0, &matrix);
```

Also if I transform a sprite with the scale vector, it becomes 100 % scaled to screen, which is odd because `desc.Width` and `desc.Height` are `243`, this is also being rendered to a "render target" that texture is a smaller resolution.

Comment: What exactly are you doing? What texture are you talking about? Does this texture contain the scene and you want to display it on the viewport? I assume, you use DirectX 9? Show your drawing code.